# Unreadable quote block/titles in the user profiles on security

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

The user profile is not readable when you use the ">" quote block. And also the titles are melted in the background.

[image: Main profile]

For a comparison we have this on meta:

[image]

Comment: Interesting - I hadn't realised you could use the ">" modifier, otherwise I may have spotted that myself:-)

Comment: Funny, that's perfectly readable, if a bit pale, on my laptop - viewed from a relatively low angle... We've discovered before that some of the colors here have opacity such that it is transparent only when viewed from a certain angle...

Comment: Aye, @avid - Looked completele blank to me, until I tilted my laptop up.

Comment: Completely unreadable on the iPad. Definitely worth fixing IMO.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed on production.